# Sharing a page containing a video on LinkedIn breaks on Android mobile app

Tags: linkedin-api

HTML5 video plays fine in Chrome (on the same device), does not play at all in LinkedIn webview.

Here's the sample video:
http://sales-dev.imeet.com/my-channel/another-webcam-test

Any idea what we should do about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Android Webview, not setting a poster on the video element throws a media error (potentially related to loading the video with a cross origin attribute). Ignoring the media error fixed the problem.